# Gather/Select rows for calculation

Tags: excel, libreoffice-calc

My question is embarrassingly simple, but a colleague asked me, and I almost never use Excel. In Mathematica, I can solve this within seconds. Let us assume a very simple arrangement consisting of a patient ID, a year of measurement, and a value:

[image]

**Question 1:** How can I create a new table consisting only of the first measurements? That is, for ID 1 the 2014 row, for ID 2 the 2015 row and for ID 3 the 2016 row.

**Question 2:** How can I create a new table that has only one line for each ID and where all found `Values` are used with a function like `MEDIAN()`? That is for ID 1 the median of 12 and 23, for ID 2 the median of 32 and 16 and for ID 3 just 4.

Comment: Are you using Excel, or LibreOffice Calc?

Comment: Well, **I** am working with LibreOffice (if I need to) but my colleagues usually work on Windoze with the real Excel. I thought I use both tags because I can somehow translate a solution to each system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your table is ordered by date (which it is in the picture), then the first question can be solved using a `VLOOKUP`

```
=VLOOKUP("1",A1:C6,3,0)
```

Replace `"1"` which whichever cell contains the ID `1` in your new table.

For question 2, you can use the following formula, again replacing `=1` with whichever cell contains ID `1` in your new table

```
{=MEDIAN(IF(A1:A6=1,C1:C6,""))}
```

Note, this is an array formula, you don't type the curly brackets `{}` directly, but simple press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>, rather than just  <kbd>ENTER</kbd> when entering the formula

This works by creating an array like this `{12,23,"","",""}` and taking the median of those numbers. `MEDIAN` ignores the strings so gives you the median of 12 and 23, as required (example for ID 1)

Comment: I think there's an extra argument in the VLOOKUP i.e. should be =VLOOKUP("1",A1:C6,2,0) or =VLOOKUP("1",A1:C6,3,0)